# How can I get a GEF GraphicalViewer to fit the view/editor that it's in?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-gef

My `ScrollingGraphicalViewer` is displayed in a ViewPart. However, if the contained diagram is larger than the ViewPart, a scrollbar appears and one cannot see the whole diagram. Instead, I would like to zoom out until the whole diagram can be seen without scrolling.

I already tried calling `viewer.zoomTo(Rectangle)`, but apparently, this method is not implemented yet. Is there another way to achieve this?

I still need the scrolling feature, so I have to use a `ScrollingGraphicalViewer`. Just when the ViewPart is opened for the first time, the zoom should be adjusted as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing GEF LayoutListener to diagram figure Override you contents editpart's #createFigure() method (e.g. DiagramEditPart#createFigure().
Something like that:

```
protected IFigure createFigure() {
    IFigure f = super.createFigure();
    f.addLayoutListener(new LayoutListener.Stub(IFigure container) {
        public void postLayout() {
             Rectangle diagramBounds = new PrecisionRectangle(container.getBounds());
             container.translateToAbsolute(diagramBounds);

             /*
              * Do the scale factor calculation based on you viewport/control size
              */

             ZoomManager zoomManager = (ZoomManager)DiuagramEditPart.this.getViewer().getProperty(ZoomManager.class.toString());
             if (zoomManager != null) {
                  zoomManager.setScale(scaleFactor);
             }
        }
    });
    return f;
}
```

Comment: If I want to be notified after the diagram has been displayed, is adding a `LayoutListener`the only solution? Or is there a way that does not involve Figures?

Comment: I'm afraid not. You need the bounding rectangle of the diagram to determine the scaling factor. Bounding rectangle is determined by the layout.